# Non central chirality in cheminformatics?

Tags: computational-chemistry, chirality, cheminformatics

What are compact cheminformatics structural representations that allow to deal correctly with axial chirality, such as in binaphthyl compounds or metal complexes?

Comment: I like the question, but it might help to add where else you have looked for this info or any ineffective structural representations you have found, so that answers don't wind up repeating what you have already tried. @Anon

Comment: Nothing much, I just tried RDKit documentation and mailing list, found nothing.

Comment: I found out there is an XML based language to do this, called FlexMol. It's pretty old, and it is not implemented in any of the major cheminfo releases (as far as I know). Hope someone who's more into cheminfo than me can give some tip!